# Turning down the time needed for a in between taps for a double tap to take place in UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, double-click

Sorry for the confusing title but I had no better way to put it. When your code has a UITapGestureRecognizer for a single tap and a double tap and:

```
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

When do a single tap it takes a bit to recognize to figure out if you are going to procede to do a double tap. In fact, it seems to me that it gives you more than enough time to double tap, so thats why i'm wondering if you can turn down the time allowed for you to do a double tap down, so it does not take forever to recognize the single tap.

To refrase it, i want to make it so that you have to press the button faster to get a double tap and if you dont it will register as two single taps.

And if you must have it here is in my **ViewDidLoad**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doSingleTap:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doDoubleTap:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this and not use other approaches? Users will not be so pleased when they have to double tap fast to go where they want. Not User friendly..

Comment: @Ty_ Well it is a game so it is appropriate for the situation

Comment: Then you should state that in you question.

Comment: @Ty_ Well I don't think it really effects the question and its not really any of your business. No offense.